# PHP: Convert String to DATETIME with Consideration of am/pm

Tags: php, datetime

I would like to convert string to php datatime with consideration of am/pm.

I would like to convert `'03/06/2015 12:17 am'` to `php` `datatime`.

I tried,

```
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i', '03/27/2015 01:17 pm');
$newDateString = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

My targeted output is `2015-03-27 13:17:00`

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: is this what you want? `$newDateString = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('03/27/2015 01:17 pm'));`

Comment: Thanks. Your Solution is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your output that you sowed, one line code is enough:-

```
<?php
echo $newDateString = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('03/27/2015 01:17 pm'));
?>
```

Output:- `2015-03-27 13:17:00`

https://eval.in/514315

Answer (score 3):

It's not an answer, just notice with more readable code-format:

*I recommend double-check expected results of **strtotime()**, sometimes it can't be used.*

for example:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Moscow");
$today = date("d-m-Y",mktime(0,0,0,4,28,2013)); // 28-04-2013, sunday
$lastWeek = strtotime("last week $today");
$thisWeek = strtotime("this week $today");
$nextWeek = strtotime("next week $today");

echo "last week - ".$lastWeek." / ".date("d-m-Y H:i\n",$lastWeek);
echo "this week - ".$thisWeek." / ".date("d-m-Y H:i\n",$thisWeek);
echo "next week - ".$nextWeek." / ".date("d-m-Y H:i\n",$nextWeek);
```

result:

```
last week - 1366574400 / 22-04-2013 00:00; expected 15-04-2013
this week - 1367179200 / 29-04-2013 00:00; expected 22-04-2013
next week - 1367784000 / 06-05-2013 00:00; expected 29-04-2013
```

so late update:
    this bug was fixed something around march 2016, version >5.6.20 and >7.0.4 has no more this problem